# Почему не работают подобные функции в цикле, а без цикла работают

Tags: python, aiogram

Я столкнулся с проблемой создания подобных функций внутри цикла. Сама функция вне цикла работает успешно и ошибок не выдаёт. У меня есть предположение, что это как-то может быть связано с асинхронностью `aiogram`, но так как я в асинхронности не так силён решил задать вопрос сюда.
Премного благодарен вам за уделенное мне время.

```
def make_callback_handler(name, data):
    @dp.callback_query_handler(lambda callback: callback.data == data)
    async def proccess_callback(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
        await bot.send_message(callback.from_user.id, "some text")

    proccess_callback.__name__ = name


for key, value in categories.items():
    make_callback_handler(key, value)
```

Comment: Стесняюсь спросить, у Вас задача вообще какая? Смысла в этом коде нет никакого

Comment: Не знаю чего вы хотите добиться но больше так не делайте. Не вставляйте хендлеры в функции, не вставляйте хендлеры в хендлеры,  не вызывайте хендлеры пожалуйста.

Comment: @MyZik не знаю получится ли донести верно мысль, но попробую. Мне нужно было некоторое(не определённое)  количество подобных хэндлеров, отличающихся только именем асинхронной фунцкии и входящими данными для самого хэндлер и асинхронной функции, которые передаются через перебор словаря. Надо это было для того, что бы при добавлении новой Inline кнопки не приходилось вручную писать отдельный хэндлер для неё, а просто добавить пару значений в словарь.

Comment: @oleksandrigo не молги бы вы пояснить почему так нельзя делать?

Comment: @G.Pblockofpurplestreet51 если я правильно помню то, при первом запуске бота регистрируются все хендлеры, а уже при получении сообщения или колбека от юзера идёт ее запуск/активация. Потому то что сделали вы меня бросает в ужас :)

Comment: Для этого не нужно изобретать велосипед, в aiogram имеется встроенная фабрика коллбэков: https://mastergroosha.github.io/telegram-tutorial-2/buttons/#_5

Comment: @oleksandrio спасибо вам большое. Я честно зеленоват, но теперь хотя бы имею понятие о том, что я должен изучить.